# How to restore database when files are claimed?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have to restore a database and am following this official documentation where I follow two steps:
- List the files
- Run the Restore command with respect to the files aforementioned.

However, I am facing "already claimed" error.

I tried to use different names but it is not possible since the backup has certain files. I also tried other answers across different domains, all have GUI.

The first command that I ran was:

```
sudo docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost \
   -U SA -P '<YourStrong@Passw0rd>' \
   -Q 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/us_national_statistics.bak"' \
   | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2
```

I got the following output:

```
LogicalName PhysicalName
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
us_national_statistics C:\Program
us_national_statistics_log C:\Program
```

Then, as per the documentation, I ran this command:

```
sudo docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
   -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourStrong@Passw0rd>' \
   -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE US_NATIONAL FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/us_national_statistics.bak" WITH MOVE "us_national_statistics" TO "C:\Program", MOVE "us_national_statistics_log" TO "C:\Program"'
```

Here, I get the following error:

```
Msg 3176, Level 16, State 1, Server 0a6a6aac7476, Line 1
File 'C:\Program\New' is claimed by 'us_national_statistics_log'(2) and 'us_national_statistics'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 0a6a6aac7476, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I expect the database to be restored.

Comment: From what I'm gathering, you are restoring a database to the same location it currently is. You'll need to change the file location or uses WITH REPLACE to overwrite it I'd suspect... assuming this isn't something unique to docker. Also, is there an option to kill existing connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restore to `C:\Program` for multiple reasons. That's not a full path (you seem to have lost the string after the first space in `Program Files`); the data and log can't both be put in the same file; you don't typically have write access to the root of any drive; and `C:\` is not valid in Docker or Linux.

You need the LogicalName, but you should not be using the PhysicalName directly, either in the case where you are restoring to Docker or Linux, or in the case where you are restoring a database alongside an existing copy that you want to keep, or in the case where you are restoring a database to a different instance (which will more than likely have a different data folder structure).

Try:

```
RESTORE DATABASE US_NATIONAL_COPY 
  FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/us_national_statistics.bak" 
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE "us_national_statistics"      TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/usns_copy.mdf",
  MOVE "us_national_statistics_log"  TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/usns_copy.ldf";
```